# Popup form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, popupwindow

I have a action link as below in my view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Benefits", "Benefit_Details", new { id = @ViewBag.policy_id })
```

When I click "Benefit" it will show the view "Benefit_Details" in same window. I need to show it as a popup form above the current view with a close button. Is it possible?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink` generates an `<a>` tag which redirects. You will need javascript/jquery to call a method that returns a partial view and display it in the DOM. Look at using a plugin such as [jQueryUI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Hi Stephen, can you please give a small example of jquery method using way for this

Comment: [Refer this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) for an example of what you could do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. 
But there is no native helpers for this. 
You need to wrote your own html helper that will render some html template, but in any way you need to use js for showing/hiding the popup

It's how to create you own helper:
1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application

You can use [jquery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message) widget (or create your own logic for showing/hiding the window)